# Round Python data frame values into a given set of numbers

Tags: python

I have a data frame with numbers in a column named "Atomic".
I'd like to round every value into the nearest number from a given set of values.

Example:

```
set : 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100

 6 -->  5
34 --> 25
70 --> 50
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

I'll suppose that you're able to put your set of numbers into a list

`set = [5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100]`

You can then define a rounding function using `min` with a `key`:

```
def custom_round(set, value):
    return min(set, key=lambda x:abs(x-value))
```

This can be combined with a list comprehension if you have many values to compute this for, e.g.

```
values = [1,2,5,6,8,9,10,25,28,99]
rounded = [custom_round(set, v) for v in values]
```

**What is happening here?**

When `min` is combined with a lambda function as a key, the function is first applied to all of the elements in the array before returning the element of the original array corresponding to the min of this new array. In the example above, the lambda function finds the absolute distance from the target `value` to each of the values you could round to, so `min` returns the element of `set` which is closest to `value`.

Comment: prob not good practice to overwrite the built-in round function, but otherwise cool!

Comment: yes, good point! I've edited the answer so as to not do that ;)

Comment: I'm trying to iterate over the data frame using the function  
`set = [0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100, 200, 250, 500,
       1000, 2000, 2500, 5000, 10000]  
def custom_round(set, value):  
   return min(set, key=lambda x:abs(x-value))  
for index1, row1 in df.iterrows():  
  df["NewAtomicRounded"] = custom_round(set, df["NewAtomic"])`  
and I get `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, 
  a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Answer (score 1):

Use `abs` + `min` + list comprehension

```
s =  [5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100]
l = [6, 34, 70]
[ k[0] for k in [ min([(i,abs(i-j)) for i in s],key=lambda x:x[1]) for j in l ] ]
#Output:
#[5, 25, 50]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'atomic':[6,34,70]})
bins = [0,5,10,20,25,50,100]
labels = bins[:-1] # [0,5,10,20,25,50]
df['binned'] = pd.cut(df.atomic, bins, labels=labels)
df

   atomic binned
0       6      5
1      34     25
2      70     50
```

Note that binned is a "category" not a number. If you need a number use

```
df['binned'] = pd.cut(df.atomic, bins, labels=labels).astype(int)
```